# Text deselecting when using Logitech mouse scroll wheel in Sierra

Tags: mouse, macos

I'm using a Logitech Performance MX mouse and since upgrading to Sierra I'm having difficulty when using my <kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> to select large amounts of text. Usually, I scroll while holding <kbd>left mouse</kbd> and this has always worked. Now when I scroll, it deselects the text that I have selected.

Could this be a driver issue?

Comment: There's several issues here already with Sierra and Logitech mice.  Do a search and see if any of those issues will fix the problem.  I believe they mostly come down to updating to the latest Logitech drivers.

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with inertia effect or choppy scrolling, I'm having problems selecting text. Wouldn't that be considered a different issue? 

In any case I installed the latest drivers and the problem is still the same. I tried a generic USB mouse I had laying around and it doesn't have the issue.

Comment: If the generic USB mouse doesn't have the problem then the issue is not with Sierra but with the Logitech mouse and how it's handling selecting text.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and I have requested moderator intervention to reopen. I am having the same issue after using the logitech update driver. Mouse wheel scrolling has improved, but still having issues with the mouse randomly firing clicks while the left mouse button is held down, and this is hugely painful when scrolling with the mousewheel while trying to select text.

Comment: Same issue on my end. Very frustrating. I'm using LCC v3.9.5.66 with MacOS 10.12.1.  As noted in the Linked SE post, the inertia problem continues to be a problem. I've notified Logitech, though they've initially responded with the most generic response: "Unplug and replug the receiver of the mouse; Try other usb ports of the computer; etc."  I suggest others contact Logitech support.

Comment: FYI: MacOS 10.12.2 fixes the Smooth Scrolling inertia issues with and without LCC 3.9.5 installed.  Unfortunately, the deselection issue when scrolling is still broken, **but only with LCC (v3.9.5.66) installed.**

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Not really a final answer, but as a ***workaround***, to select long texts, you can

1. make the initial selection
2. release the mouse button
3. scroll to the destination
4. press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse click/hold again, to finish the selection.

---

Just sharing my findings, since I'm also annoyed with this issue: as Dolan Antenucci commented, uninstalling LCC will normalize the behavior of hold-mouse-left-button combined with scrolling, but at the cost of losing mouse customization. Not an option for me.

Curiously, I've been searching and searching for hours, and seems no one else here is complaining about this. The closest I could find was a report of a bug in a UI framework written in Python, but so close in behavior that for a second (or a couple, or more ;-)) I had to question myself if it's really a coincidence (I now, I now..).

See https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5058

There they describe (almost?) exactly what I believe is happening here: Scrolling generates a mouse up event for previously pressed button.

To verify, you can try this: on a browser, press and hold the right button. Then move the mouse over an option of the pop-up menu (say, "back"), then scroll the wheel. The option is selected, as if you had released the button.

The same is occurring with text selection. Do this: with mouse left-click-and-hold, select some text, "freeze any mouse movements" (explain later), then scroll down (but not too much, keep the already selected text visible). The text that remains selected is only the one who was selected just before the scroll movement (as if you had released the button just before start scrolling). Then stop scrolling, hold shift, and do some mouse movement. In response to the smallest move, the text between is automatically added to the selection, and after this you can even release the shift, no matter anymore, go keep moving the mouse (provided that you don't move the scroll) to continue tuning selection. This is exactly what should have happened if you had released the button just before start scrolling (aka mouse up event), do some scroll, then pressed/hold shift, and next clicked/hold again the mouse button, to do the final mouse selection movements.

The only catch is that, if while holding the button and after some scrolling (who "wrongly" generated a mouse button up event), you do any mouse movement, in response to this move, (maybe in an attempt) to honor the fact that the you are still holding the button, the system immediately generates a mouse button down event.

That's why you think the scroll de-selects the text: normally, when someone do some scroll to add selection, do without moving the mouse, but tends to make some final mouse movements after the scroll, tu adjust the end of the selection. Try holding the button, make some selection thru moving, freeze mouse movement, scroll (keep freezing), release button, move mouse (note, the selection don't go away), then shift + click/hold, when the mouse reach the destination point. Since you released the button just before restarting mouse movements, when you do the new moves, the system will not generate a mouse button down event, once there is no need to "honor" this state (after all, the button is already up).

It's not the scroll who de-selects the text: it's the mouse movement, after scrolling, while keeping the mouse button down.

I think it's an attempt to maintain/regain system consistency, since the last info passed thru was, essentially, wrong: the mouse button up event, as a consequence of a scroll movement, should never been occurred.

I'm going to report this to logitech, maybe if presented with some more tech explanation they will fix the problem. (God, is so painful to use they site send a simple message, anyone knows a easier way?)

Comment: https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D53100005mJtCNCA0/performance-mx-macos-sierra-problem

Answer (score 0):

2021, I was getting similar issues with Logitech M510 (firmware 62.00.0013), [Logitech Options](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options) 8.36.76 and LCC 3.9.8 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. It also happened when trying to move windows around.

**Fixed by uninstalling LCC (Logitech Control Center).**

Comment: I've been noticing similar issues on macOS Catalina, when trying to drag & drop windows or selecting text. I will post more here once I find another solution, since there is no LCC installed on this mac and the version of Logitech Options is the same.

Comment: I believe my problem was on the Logitech mouse M510 itself. It worked for about 4 years; now it has the issue on Catalina and Mojave  and it works fine on a M705.

Comment: issue psoted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415537/trying-to-drag-drop-sometimes-is-reset-multiple-times-during-drag-with-mouse-l/415538#415538)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues with MX Anywhere 2(Big Sur 11.2), installing Logitech Control Center solved my problem. Although it tells "No logitech Device Found".