# Mouse wheel deselects text on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, mouse, macos

This issue was previously reported here: [MacOS Sierra; Text deselecting when using scroll-wheel with Logitech mouse.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257298/macos-sierra-text-deselecting-when-using-scroll-wheel-with-logitech-mouse?newreg=23b4ee4990454a0fbf69ae2c64a8e9af), but there is not a solution, the question is a year and a half old, and the issue is closed without higher rep.

Using 10.13.2.

Text selection stops and restarts when using a mouse wheel. This problem does not occur when using the trackpad.

The issue is not Logitech specific--I use a Kensington trackball and work and a Logitech trackball at home, and I have the same problem with both.

The posted select-scroll-shift-select solution works, but is frustrating.